# Checkout With Multiple Addresses For Guest Customer?

Tags: magento2.4.5, multishipping

Is it possible to allow guest to ship with mutliple addresses. I want to allow multi-shipping checkout for guest customers in Magento 2. Any Idea Would Be Appreciated?

Thanks.